# RegEx: Capture character only if previous groups matching

Tags: regex

I'm implementing a regular expression to match an **absolute URI** as defined in `RFC 3986`.

- in the current state there is no capturing of path, query and fragment
- additionaly to the specified `authority` there are groups capturing `user`, `password` and the `authless authority`

Actually I'm able to capture the following URIs.

https://regex101.com/r/aXYPbl/2

```
RegEx

~^(?<scheme>.+?):(?://(?<authority>(?:(?<user>.+?)(?::(?<password>.+?))?@)+(?<authlessAuthority>.+)?))?$~

---
Examples

https://example.com
https://@example.com
https://user@example.com
https://user:password@example.com
```

My current problem URI is the second one. This URI is invalid and should not be matched while the `@` character should not be captured within the authority while there is no authentication provided in the URI.

So my question is:

How can I exclude the `@` character from the authority group if there is no authentication provided?

I'm sure it's pretty simple. But I currently lost my focus.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aXYPbl/3

Comment: Add a negative look behind: `(?:(?<!/)@)`. Also I think the `+` after the credentials allows multiple set of credentials. I think you want `?`

Answer (score 0):

You may require the "authlessAuthority" group to start with any char but `@`:

```
^(?<scheme>.+?):(?://(?<authority>(?:(?<user>.+?)(?::(?<password>.+?))?@)?(?<authlessAuthority>[^@].*)?))?$
                                                                                               ^^^^
```

Here, `[^@]` is a negated character class that matches any char but `@`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXYPbl/3)

Also, you might be interested in an [*Email Address Regular Expression That 99.99% Works*](https://emailregex.com/).